# Wildfly 10 Infinispan JCache: @CacheResult causes "Member of array type or annotation type must be annotated @NonBinding"

Tags: java, cdi, wildfly-10, jcache, infinispan-8

I'm trying to use the Infinispan JCache annotations within Wilfly 10. My Wildfly installation has the Wildfly-Camel extension (http://wildfly-extras.github.io/wildfly-camel/).

I would like to use method level caching:

```
@CacheResult
public Connector getConnector(String name) {
   ...
}
```

Relevant Maven dependencies of my app:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.cache</groupId>
        <artifactId>cache-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
        <artifactId>infinispan-jcache</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.4.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My `beans.xml`:

```
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    version="1.2" bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
    <interceptors>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheResultInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCachePutInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheRemoveEntryInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.InjectedCacheRemoveAllInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.CacheResultInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.CachePutInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.CacheRemoveEntryInterceptor</class>
        <class>org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.CacheRemoveAllInterceptor</class>
    </interceptors>
</beans>
```

However, I get the following error, when the application is being deployed:

```
WELD-001121: Member of array type or annotation type must be annotated @NonBinding:  [EnhancedAnnotatedMethodImpl] public abstract javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult.cachedExceptions()
```

Which is strange as all methods in `javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult` are annotated with `@Nobinding`

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Have you tested behavior removing **bean-discovery-mode="annotated"** from beans.xml?
- Have you assigned a cacheName to **@CacheResult** annotation?
- It would be good to enable TRACE debug in standalone.xml to "org.infinispan"

I have it running with "*bean-discovery-mode=all*" (if not specified in beans.xml, takes this as default) and indicating only the last four interceptor classes: org.infinispan.jcache.annotation.Cache*

Hope it helps, keep posted.